# How to copy finished ipk file to host /tmp after compilation?

Tags: bitbake, file-copying

I need to copy a finished ipk file after compilation to, lets say, host computer /tmp . How do I do this?

I have been googling around but I have not been able to find out posts addressing exactly this problem. I'm using Kirkstone.